# When using MySQL Workbench, I keep losing connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, rdbms

Here are the two types of errors I get:
ERROR 2006: 2006: MySQL server has gone away
and
ERROR 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Which happens every couple minutes are so when I am applying a script.

Here is what I have tried:
[Increasing the DBMS connection read time out, time out, and keep-alive internal (under Preferences > SQL Editor) as suggested by another post, however, the errors continue to persist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyqQF.png)

Comment: What have you increased the connection timeout to, and is that value longer than "every couple minutes"?

Comment: @EricJ. 90,000 for keep-alive interval and read time out and 86,400 for time out, all values are in seconds